# Merge array objects in JavaScript using underscore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, angular, underscore.js

I have two arrays and i want to combine them to get common result.
array should be combine on the basis of **user_id** not on index 
How would i do this?

**Array 1**:

```
var array1 = [{
  "name": "Smart Test Pool",
  "user_id": 1,
  "total_time": "15.0",
}];
```

**Array 2**:

```
var array2 = [{
  "user_id": 1,
  "total_hours_worked_milliseconds": 60060000,
  "total_time_unshedule_milliseconds": 540000
}];
```

**Result** :

```
var result = [{
  "name": "Smart Test Pool",
  "user_id": 1,
  "total_time": "15.0",
  "total_hours_worked_milliseconds": 60060000,
  "total_time_unshedule_milliseconds": 540000
}];
```

Comment: It seems to me that you want to combine the properties of the elements of the array, not the arrays themselves. I assume then, that you want to combine element 0 of the first array with element 0 of the next one. Is that correct?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: If you use es2015, you can do, `var arr1 = ['item1', 'item2']; var arr2 = ['item3', 'item4']; var merge = [...arr1, ...arr2]`, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: suppose you have data of the form [{data1}] and [{}{data2}]... now would you want [{data1 data 2}] .. this is just one of the possibilities then can be a lot of these ...

Answer (score 5):

You can merge objects using:

**1- Plain JS Methods:**

You can use `.map()`, `.find()` and `Object.assign()`:

```
let result = array1.map(o => Object.assign(
    {}, o, array2.find(o2 => o2["user_id"] === o["user_id"])
));
```

Or spread syntax:

```
let result = array1.map((o, i) => (
  {...o,...array2.find(o2 => o2["user_id"] === o["user_id"])}
));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let array1 = [{
  "name": "Smart Test Pool",
  "user_id": 1,
  "total_time": "15.0",
}];

let array2 = [{
  "user_id": 1,
  "total_hours_worked_milliseconds": 60060000,
  "total_time_unshedule_milliseconds": 540000
}];

let result = array1.map(o => Object.assign(
    {}, o, array2.find(o2 => o2["user_id"] === o["user_id"])
));

console.log(result);
```

**2- Underscore**

You can use `.map()` and `.extend()` methods:

```
let result = _.map(array1, function(o) {
    return _.extend({}, o, _.find(array2, function(o2) {
        return o2["user_id"] === o["user_id"]
    }));
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let array1 = [{
  "name": "Smart Test Pool",
  "user_id": 1,
  "total_time": "15.0",
}];

let array2 = [{
  "user_id": 1,
  "total_hours_worked_milliseconds": 60060000,
  "total_time_unshedule_milliseconds": 540000
}];

let result = _.map(array1, function(o) {
 return _.extend({}, o, _.find(array2, function(o2) {
        return o2["user_id"] === o["user_id"]
    }));
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: **To Downvoter:** Is there something wrong with my answer? If yes, please let me know.

Comment: i want to merge on user_id not on index

Comment: @Rahul You should have mention this in your question. Anyway I've updated my answer.